# The Bureau is not giving me any missions any more

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

After doing 1 major mission, Codebreaker DLC Mission and several minor missions, as well as agent dispatches, I am not getting any missions any more. The Director is not in his Bureau, so I cannot talk to him and all other NPC have nothing new to say.

[image]

As you can see, there are no more missions available on the screen.

**How do I proceed with the game?**

Comment: Have you tried pressing F5 and checking where that leads you? Usually there are quests inside the base between the major missions.